# Install specific tomcat version through apt-get

Tags: ubuntu, debian, tomcat, apt

I would like to install on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine a specific version of Tomcat.
The required one is the 6.0.0, and I want to install it using apt-get.

In the default PPAs that version is not available. Is there some PPA to add that provides that specific version?

I looked at these ones:

- https://launchpad.net/tomcat6/+packages (older tomcat: 6.0.28)
- https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=tomcat6 (older tomcat 6.0.45)

I need that specific version for testing a vulnerability and I need it from apt-get since the vulnerability is in the init.d script provided by Ubuntu or Debian installation.

Thanks